# jsfiddle and codepen not storing window.localStorage entries

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am trying to store some items from an exercise I'm doing in codepen over to the localStorage object of the browser, but it doesn't seem to work.

I then tried the same thing over on jsFiddle, it also doesn't work.
[Here's the link to the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/au9q0s15/)

Lastly I tried bringing the same code local to my desktop, everything is working as expected.

In all three cases here is how I am testing for success / failure:

In the Chrome console i am executing the following:

```
localStorage.getItem('_wikiwiggs_recipe_book_AppleJuice');
```

Any thoughts as to why I may be experiencing this?

Comment: Key name is `_wikiwiggs_recipe_book_AppleJuice`

Comment: Sorry, yeah copied a different version, but same problem occurred.

Comment: Change the question to be accurate with the jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after my way...... too long pursuit of this answer, I have been able to do the following:

The answer for my intentions is to simply:

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem('_wikiwiggs_recipe_book_AppleJuice'))
```

from within my codepen/jsFiddle.

I can't do this directly from the console manually, because I do not really have the privileges (for good reason) to essentially spoof the site author.

The only way that I have found to be able troubleshoot via javascript directly is to use this method.

Thanks for the help enapupe & Bobby Speirs - The answer given definitely reinforced the reasoning for this behavior.

For me though, leaving off the `console.log()` from your answer as trivial as this may sound, tripped me up, because I was still not seeing how I was going to troubleshoot the code.

Answer (score 4):

If you open up your dev tools, then look under the application tab, you'll see that you're storing the item with the key '_wikiwiggs_recipe_book_AppleJuice'.

You can access this item from within the JSFiddle shell with `localStorage.getItem('_wikiwiggs_recipe_book_AppleJuice');`

Since JSFiddle loads the code under an iframe, you must select it on your developer console before running the above command:
[image: developer tools frame selection]

Comment: OK, so I see what you are talking about via the Application tab, but I'm still really confused as to why I can't access this via the console directly. Chrome is obviously willing to show me the data, as you have described. I can even Edit & Delete from here (under the Applications Tab). I'm not getting the reasoning.

Comment: It's just the way the JSFiddle application works. When you're using localStorage in the JSFiddle shell, it's saving it to a different context than what your browser uses when you run code through your console. Try typing localStorage.setItem('test', 'test'); into your console, and you'll see it saves it under a different location in the Application tab.

Comment: That's exactly how I verified that things were working for me locally. My question that comes from all of this is, how do I navigate the context the way jsFiddle does, so that I can access my data for troubleshooting? I'm still confused here?

Comment: It seems like what is really happening, is that my calls to **localStorage** are being Hi-Jacked and converted into **sessionStorage** calls, because it is forming the context as it is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). I will play with this some more, and upVote your answer, because it has definitely helped shine more light on the issue. Thanks.